# FATAL ERROR in native method: ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical: failed bounds check

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, gnucobol

I'm trying to connect my Java code with a C program (translated using GnuCobol) using JNI. Unfortunately, I can't access the C source code and rewrite in Java, so I've created a wrapper C program to call it.

## Help with the following ERROR

```
ProgramX.cbl:112: Attempt to reference unallocated memory (Signal SIGSEGV)
```

The error occurs on the second attempt to get some response from the C program.

Log generated using -Xcheck:jni

```
ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical: release array failed bounds check, incorrect pointer returned ? array: 0x00007fd10a6514c0 carray: 0x00007fd104a93400
GuardedMemory(0x00007fd10a651330) base_addr=0x00007fd104a933e0 tag=0x00007fd104a93290 user_size=324 user_data=0x00007fd104a93400
  Header guard @0x00007fd104a933e0 is OK
  Trailer guard @0x00007fd104a93544 is BROKEN
  User data appears to be in use
FATAL ERROR in native method: ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical: failed bounds check
```

And I need help to figure out the cause of this.

## Sources

The java snippet

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("gnucobollib");
    }

    public native void callGnuCobol(byte[] request, byte[] response);

    private void invokeNativeCall(AbstractData... args) {
        // Changed size from 16162 to the correct size 16164 
        // as suggested in comment by Alex Cohn
        byte[] responseBytes = new byte[16164];
        String request = "Personal sensitive data";
        callGnuCobol(utm1.getBytes(), responseBytes);
        String resonse = new String(responseBytes);
    }
```

The `gnucobollib` main C source

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cpy/utm1.h"
#include "cpy/utm2.h"
#include "jni/testJavaJni.h"

static int cobc_runtime_initialized = 0;

static void init_cobc_runtime() {
    if (!cobc_runtime_initialized) {
        printf("initializing cobc runtime\n");
        cob_init(0, NULL);
        cobc_runtime_initialized = 1;
    }
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_att_ub_ub2l_cbct545_Cbct545Program_callGnuCobol(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jbyteArray request,  jbyteArray response)
{
    init_cobc_runtime();
    jbyte* bufferRequest = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, request, NULL);
    jbyte* bufferResponse = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, response, NULL);

    CALLBANANA((struct utm1*)&bufferRequest[0], (struct utm2*)&bufferResponse[0]);

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, request, bufferRequest, 0);
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, response, bufferResponse, 0);

}
```

The method `CALLBANANA` is from a translated Cobol code using GNUCobol.

## Temporary Solution

Handle all signals direct on C wrapper program. Despite of the error message, everything works fine and million of calls to GnuCobol happened without any issue.

Still pending the recompile of the code to latest version of GnuCobol

Comment: On the face of it, the JVM tells you that your function writes to more than 16162 bytes of bufferResponse. If this size should be `sizeof(struct utm2)`, the reason could be that you did not take alignment into account. But these are speculations. You should step through this wrapper in debugger, or add log prints.

Comment: The overrun appears to be detected when `ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical` is called. Where does this call come from? The function you've shown us only calls `ReleaseByteArrayElements`. Also, the size of the buffer in question appears to be 324 bytes. What buffers do you have that match that size?

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for the suggestion, changed to 16164, but didn't work.

Comment: @Michael, the buffer in question does not have explicit relation with request or response, because even changing both sizes to higher or lower values it resulted in the same error message.

Comment: @Michael, good catch about the size, my count gives 356 though. At any rate, the crash does look unrelated to `struct utm2`, and most likely not coming from **CALLBANANA**

Comment: @AlexCohn: The extra 32 bytes are made up of the header/trailer guard data, the size value, and a tag.

Comment: Just some notes: If you always start with `CALLBANANA` then you can drop your manual initialization and just compile the program with `-fimplicit-init` (for completeness it would be good to specify which `cobc` options are used to compile the program and ideally add a test program (just containing the `LINKAGE`, do a `DISPLAY` of the bufferRequest and `MOVE` to bufferResponse) that produces the error, too.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @SimonSobisch. I will take me a few days to recompile it with the latest gnucobol, since I don't have the source.